# Laravel doesn't read post request with FormData

Tags: php, laravel, postman, form-data

The `dd(Request::instance()->getContent());` statement shows:

```
"
----------------------------545652777124128130660951\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="firstname"\r\n
\r\n
fakeName\r\n
----------------------------545652777124128130660951--\r\n
"
```

The request is sent with the Postman. 
The headers:
'Content-Type':'application/json', 
'Accept':'application/json, text/plain'

**Problem:** 
The `Request::instance()->all();` returns an empty array. Why?

Comment: @ChristianBaumann why am I getting down vote?

Answer (score 1):

oops 
This is the fix: 
Change this header: 
`Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=<calculated when request is sent>` 
Which is set by postman. 
Shouldn't have touched this header.